# How to execute remote command using PuTTY over Telnet

Tags: command-line, putty, telnet

I was created a `.bat` file to run PuTTY and it successfully runs. The problem now is, the command line I was key in were not executed, any solution for this?

My `.bat` command is:

```
putty -telnet -P 15555 test-PC -m C:\Users\tslai\Desktop\commands.txt
```

I'm connecting using Telnet, and I have a specific port number, which is 15555, the server name's is test-PC. `commands.txt` is the arguments that I make.

In `commands.txt`: only have a arguments, and it was tested can work properly if running directly by using command prompt.

Answer (score 4):

The `-m` command-line switch of PuTTY works for the SSH only, not for the Telnet.

See [PuTTY documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-m) (emphasis mine):

> **3.8.3.6 `-m`: read a remote command or script from a file**
>
> The -m option performs a similar function to the ‘Remote command’ box
>   in the **SSH panel** of the PuTTY configuration box (see [section 4.18.1](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-command)).
>   However, the `-m` option expects to be given a local file name, and it
>   will read a command from that file.

There's no way to execute a command on the server automatically with PuTTY over the Telnet protocol.

---

Though you might be able to use [Plink (PuTTY command-line connection tool)](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html).

As with PuTTY, you cannot use the `command` parameter as that works with the SSH only.

But you might be able to use input redirection:

```
plink.exe -telnet -P 15555 test-PC < C:\Users\tslai\Desktop\commands.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Telnet Scripting Tool](http://support.moonpoint.com/downloads/windows/network/Telnet/tst10.php) is a program that provides the capability to script telnet sessions. Perhaps it would be a viable alternative for you.